# MIPS Dynamic Array allocation

Tags: dynamic, mips, dynamic-arrays

I would like to allow the user to tell me how many numbers they would like to enter then allow them to enter them and store them in an array.I would like to call it myArray

I cannot find anything clear anywhere.

```
print_str ("How many numbers would you like ot enter? ")
li $v0, 5                       #taking input in from user
syscall
move $s7, $v0

li $s6, 0           `           # i = 0
inputLoop:
    bgt $s6, $s7, exitInputLooop



li $a0, $s7
sll $s7, $s7, 2                 #user input x 4 for mememory allocation

li      $v0,9             # (1) Allocate a block of memory
    li      $a0, ($s7)             # 4 bytes long
    syscall                   # $v0 <-- address
    move  myArray, ($s7)            # (2) Make a safe copy


    addi $s6, $s6, 4                #i++
exitInputLoop
```

Comment: _"I would like to call it myArray"_ You can't. If you declare a label `myArray`, then it has its own address. Now, what you _can_ do is store the address of your dynamically allocated memory block _at_ `myArray`, which you can then use like so: `lw $a0, myArray` `lw $v0, ($a0)`.

Comment: `syscall`s return their values in `$v0`.